# Kotlin: how to declare a generic function with fixed set of admissible type parameters?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to write a function that converts a pair of integer numbers to pair of `BigInteger`. Allowed parameter types are  `Int`, `Long`, and `BigInteger`:

```
fun <A, B> foo(a: A, b: B) {
    val x = if (a is BigInteger) a else a.toBigInteger()
    val y = if (b is BigInteger) b else b.toBigInteger()
    return Pair(x, y)
}
```

Is it possible to inform the Kotlin compiler that `A` and `B` must be in the set of `Int`, `Long`,`BigInteger`?

Comment: What exactly is your use case for this? Since there is no other place where you can have a reference that is of type "Int or Long", what is the benefit of this function over just converting to `BigInteger` on the call site when necessary? I would find `Pair(bigInt, someLong.toBigInteger())` pretty clear already

Comment: @Joffrey You are right, we can do conversion at the call site, but I just looked for more friendly interface.  And the question is not only about this particular case, but about the general limitations of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is currently possible, or would have enough use for them to consider implementing it. I couldn't find any specific mention of the lack of support, but the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#upper-bounds) for (multiple) upper bounds says that:

> The passed type must satisfy all conditions of the where clause simultaneously. In the above example, the T type must implement both CharSequence and Comparable.

The only clean (ish) solution would probably be overloading, however this would introduce a lot of duplication if you're allowing any combinations of `Int`, `Long` etc.

Comment: Thank you, seems the overloading is the cleanest solution.